# Accomplishing Ctrl-z + bg in one step?

Tags: bash, terminal, console

We can use Ctrl-z to stop the current job followed by

```
bg
```

to send it to the background, but can we do this in one action that doesn't briefly pause the execution of the program?

Is there a combined

```
Ctrl-z + bg
```

type command that we can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no, but check https://superuser.com/questions/378018/how-can-i-do-ctrl-z-and-bg-in-one-keypress-to-make-process-continue-in-backgroun for a hacky solution to implement a faster backgrounding.